# In Redactor WYSIWYG editor, how can I add a <dl> tag?

Tags: wysiwyg, redactor, redactor.js

This question applies to both Redactor 2 and 3. I'm searching for a way to add or edit `<dl>`, `<dt>` and `<dd>` tags. Does anyone know of a way to do this out of the box, or with a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I found that it works if you edit the HTML – so the element is supported by Redactor – but that a `<dl>` gets transformed to a `<p>` when you paste it.

Unfortunately that defeats the purpose of a WYSIWYG editor :-/